# Select a movie and all its genres on one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have 3 tables: shows(pk: id), show_genres(pk: id, fk: show_id, genre_id), genres(pk: id).

A show can have multiple genres and I need to take them all.

My table looks for a show looks like this now:

| title | year | genres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sherlock | 2016 | Crime |
| Sherlock | 2016 | Documentary |

For every genre of a show it makes another row, instead of adding only the second genre.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT title, year, genres.name genres
FROM shows
LEFT JOIN show_genres ON shows.id=show_genres.show_id
LEFT JOIN genres ON show_genres.genre_id=genres.id
```

I have tried with SELECT DISTINCT and other suggestions from other questions.
Also from my research I did not find anything that could work.

Any suggestions about what I should try or what do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `STRING_AGG` alone with `GROUP BY` to get one row for each movie with all genres aggregated in string. Your query would be like this

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    year, 
    STRING_AGG(genres.name, ',') genres 
FROM shows 
LEFT JOIN show_genres ON shows.id = show_genres.show_id 
LEFT JOIN genres ON show_genres.genre_id = genres.id
GROUP BY title, year
```

Comment: @Sarayu if it helps you - as I am pretty sure it does - please accept the answer.

Comment: @JimJones   I already accepted it, but I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. Nonetheless, my feedback has been recorded